# How to set validation layers from within program rather than env var?

Tags: c++, environment-variables, vulkan, validation-layers

The official [vulkan documentation](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.2.131.1/windows/layer_configuration.html) claims:

> Applications may programmatically activate layers via the vkCreateInstance() entry point.

And this is given as alternative to setting an environment variable. However, nothing else is said in this section about how to set them. We can read the [official docs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/vkCreateInstance.html) of VkCreateInstance which say nothing about validaiton layers, so we can look at the [CreateInfo](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VkInstanceCreateInfo.html) instead. In here the only relevant field seems to be `ppEnabledLayerNames`.

Based on everything so far, one might think that passing the correct strings to the create info is enough to set the layers. So one might do this:

```cpp
    const std::vector<const char*> VALIDATION_LAYERS = {"VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation"};

    // Create Vulkan instance to communicate with the loader
    vk::InstanceCreateInfo create_info = {};
    create_info.pApplicationInfo = &program_info,
    create_info.enabledLayerCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(VALIDATION_LAYERS.size()),
    create_info.ppEnabledLayerNames = VALIDATION_LAYERS.data(),
    create_info.enabledExtensionCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(required_extensions.size()),
    create_info.ppEnabledExtensionNames = required_extensions.data();

    auto [result, instance] = vk::createInstanceUnique(create_info);
```

I am running the above snippet within a larger application. If I manually set the env var as described in the docs, it runs. If I however do not set the env var and instead rely only on the above snippet, my program crashes on instance creation.

Since the docs explicitly say you can set things programmatically but don't seem to say how, what should you do to avoid relying on the env var?

To be more specific, the error I get when running the snippet occurs in the hpp header, an assertion fails:

```
typename vk::ResultValueType<vk::UniqueHandle<Type, Dispatch> >::type vk::createResultValue(vk::Result, T&, const char*, const typename vk::UniqueHandleTraits<Type, Dispatch>::deleter&) [with T = vk::Instance; D = vk::DispatchLoaderStatic; typename vk::ResultValueType<vk::UniqueHandle<Type, Dispatch> >::type = vk::ResultValue<vk::UniqueHandle<vk::Instance, vk::DispatchLoaderStatic> >; typename vk::UniqueHandleTraits<Type, Dispatch>::deleter = vk::ObjectDestroy<vk::NoParent, vk::DispatchLoaderStatic>]: Assertion `result == Result::eSuccess' failed.
```

Analyzing the stack with gdb shows this occurs on instance creation.
The specific error code that makes the assertion fail is `vk::Result::eErrorLayerNotPresent`.

And as an added piece of information, calling: `auto [result, availableLayers] = vk::enumerateInstanceLayerProperties();`

Immediately before calling instance creation returns an empty array.

Comment: The posted code looks fine and should work.

Comment: I added some additional information, it does not work unless the layers path is specified through an environment variable.

Comment: When you set the environment variable, do you also set `VK_LAYER_PATH`? If so, you still need to set it for the layers to be found.

Comment: That is what I am talking about in the issue. Reading the docs it would seem that you can do everything programatically, but I only manage to get my program working if I set VK_LAYER_PATH

Comment: Which layers are available and where they are located is not something you can have control over since it can be different from system to system. What you "can" have control over programatically is **which** layers are enabled.

Comment: Why do you link to years old documentation? Do you have a reasonable version of SDK installed?

Comment: I linked the first one I found through my search that was perhaps a mistake on my end. I had the 1.2.176 sdk installed, although right now I am trying to install the parts of the sdk directly throguh conan. i.e. the layers are not the ones in teh sdk but the conan package with the same verison.

Comment: @Makogan Well there's your problem. Official SDK installs the paths into registry where they can be discovered by Vulkan. Not sure what unofficial sources do...

Comment: I mean it can be made to work by exporting the environment variable, I just miss understood the documentaiton and thought it could be done without relying on env vars

Comment: It is done without env vars, if it is the **official** SDK. If you use someone's unofficial package, you need to ask them what they are doing.

Comment: With the official sdk you have to call the setup script, which sets the env var. Or at minimum I was never able to run my code properly without calling the setup script (I would usually tell my profile to call it).

Comment: If you use portable SDK without installing it, then obviously you need to set the paths yourself. Anyway, here have the [layer discovery docs](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Loader/blob/master/loader/LoaderAndLayerInterface.md#layer-discovery).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply `VkInstanceCreateInfo::ppEnabledLayerNames` enables layers.

Layers have to be available before they can be enabled. That can be determined by `vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties`.

Obviously, Vulkan is not magic and the Loader needs to know where to look for extensions. That system is outlined in [LoaderAndLayerInterface.md](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Loader/blob/master/loader/LoaderAndLayerInterface.md#layer-discovery).

Basically on Windows it looks in canonical path in registry. On Linuxes it looks in canonical paths in filesystem. These will be set by installable versions of the SDK. Or `VK_LAYER_PATH` env variable can override the default paths.